# How to close Express server inside Jest afterAll hook

Tags: node.js, express, jestjs, axios, integration-testing

I am trying to write integration tests for my Express server using Jest. Since Jest runs tests in parallel (and I would like to avoid running tests in sequence using `--runInBand`), I am using the [get-port](https://github.com/sindresorhus/get-port) library to find a random available port so that different test suites don't have port collisions.

My tests all run successfully, the only problem is that the server is failing to close down properly inside the `afterAll` hook. This causes Jest to print the following in the console...

```
Jest did not exit one second after the test run has completed.
This usually means that there are asynchronous operations that weren't stopped in your tests.
Consider running Jest with `--detectOpenHandles` to troubleshoot this issue.
```

When I use the `--detectOpenHandles` flag, Jest just hangs after tests complete. Nothing gets printed to the console.

Here is my test code...

```js
let axios = require('axios')
const getPort = require('get-port')
const { app } = require('../../index')
const { Todo } = require('../../models')

// set reference to server to access
// from within afterAll hook
let server

beforeAll(async () => {
  const port = await getPort()
  axios = axios.create({ baseURL: `http://localhost:${port}` })
  server = app.listen(port)
})

afterAll(() => {
  server.close()
})

describe('GET /todos', () => {
  it('returns a list of todos', async () => {
    const { data: todos } = await axios.get('/todos')
    todos.forEach(todo => {
      expect(Todo.validate(todo)).toEqual(true)
    })
  })
})
```

Comment: I'd recommend using supertest, then you don't need to do that manually (plus you get a nice API for making requests and asserting on responses).

Comment: This issue with supertest is the whole reason I tried switching over to axios in the first place... https://github.com/visionmedia/supertest/issues/520#issuecomment-557528742

Comment: Ah, sorry. It's unfortunate that you've run into the same problem again trying to escape it!

Comment: Starting to think this might be an issue with Jest itself. Opened an issue here... https://github.com/facebook/jest/issues/9227

Answer (score 1):

I am on that github thread on this issue. Here is exactly the configuration that works for me. In package.json

```
"test": "jest --no-cache  --detectOpenHandles --runInBand --forceExit",
```

Here is the configuration in test file

```
afterEach(async () => {
  await server.close();
});

afterAll(async () => {
  await new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(() => resolve(), 10000)); // avoid jest open handle error
});

beforeEach(() => {
  // eslint-disable-next-line global-require
  server = require('../index');
  jest.setTimeout(30000);
});
```

OR you have only afterAll to set timeout and settimeout for each test in the test body individually.That's example below

```
afterEach(async () => {
  await server.close();
});

afterAll(async () => {
  await new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(() => resolve(), 10000)); // avoid jest open handle error
});

beforeEach(() => {
  // eslint-disable-next-line global-require
  server = require('../index');
});


describe('POST /customers', () => {
  jest.setTimeout(30000);
  test('It creates a customer', async () => {
    const r = Math.random()
      .toString(36)
      .substring(7);
    const response = await request(server)
      .post('/customers')
      .query({
        name: r,
        email: `${r}@${r}.com`,
        password: 'beautiful',
      });
    // console.log(response.body);
    expect(response.body).toHaveProperty('customer');
    expect(response.body).toHaveProperty('accessToken');
    expect(response.statusCode).toBe(200);
  });
});
```

Comment: This is far too hacky in my opinion. There's gotta be another way, and without using --runInBand which goes against the spirit of Jest. If this is indeed the only way around the issue, then there is an issue with Jest itself.

Comment: There is I guess. This github thread on the issue already posted points to that: https://github.com/visionmedia/supertest/issues/520#issuecomment-557528742

Answer (score 1):

Answers above didn't worked for me. I fixed it by this way:

In the main server file, I added this function to close server:

```js
app.closeServer = () => {
  server.close();
};
```

Then I used it in test code by this code block:

```js
afterAll(async () => {
  await new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(() => resolve(), 500)); // avoid jest open handle error
  app.closeServer();
});
```